# I'm getting problem with image tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning from freecodecamp.org and its my first tribute project. Everything is good but I'm getting problem with image tag. I've to submit my project online. I'm copying image link from google or any website and trying to put in src/href section but the image is not showing up on the webpage. I hope you understand and answer my question as soon as possible. Thanks.

I've tried different links and solutions from different websites. But nothing is working.

Comment: Please share your code, at least the single line for your img tag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ It is pretty much impossible for you to get any help without adding your code to the question _ You will need to add HTML & maybe CSS as well _ so that contributors can work with the code to help put things right _ It would be a good idea to visit SO Help Center and look at the 'Asking' section and specifically 'How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: While you're [edit]ing your question, make sure you're more specific than "nothing is working". For now I'm voting to close the question as unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

becauce most of the developers use relative address if you want to find the address of the link you must right click on the (img link src or background-image src) in the developer tools (crtl + shift + i) and then select "open in new tab" so you can see the link of the img

Comment: Thanks Man! It worked. Its helped me a lot with my project. I was stuck from a week now in my project. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you cant have a picture to display from a `href=""` if you want to display the picture you need to add the link in the `src=""` section. `href` is used when you want to redirect someone when they click on the image.

`<img src="your.google.picture.link" href="go.to.youtube.on.click">`

Hope this helped you out <3